# Can solana accounts be made immutable?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, account

I have recently started learning about solana development and realised that solana accounts created by solana programs are mutable. Is there any way we can make them immutable? Also can you please refer me some resources where I can learn how to do it using anchor if it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as a program is mutable, the program's accounts are also effectively mutable.
This is because the program's upgrade authority has the ability to update the program at any time with new instructions to modify the program's accounts.